# How to fix components display if run one class from another?

Tags: java, swing

Have a class with some components on it like jpanel with buttons etc. When i run this class from a main method inside this class it works fine. The problem is that when i try to run this class constructor from another class the components disappar.

```
      CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("Web Cam");
    CanvasFrame capturecanvas =new CanvasFrame("Preview");


    Canvas capturecanva = new Canvas();

    JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel capturepanel=new JLabel();
    JButton captureBtn;
    JButton acceptBtn;
    JButton retakeBtn;
    String currentCapture;
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

   int total_Faces;

    public FaceDetector(int interruptionCommnand) throws IOException
        {
            captureInterrupt();
        }
    public FaceDetector() throws IOException, FrameGrabber.Exception
        {

            FrameGrabber grabber = new VideoInputFrameGrabber(0);    
            canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            capturecanvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            canvas.setSize(800,600);
            canvas.setLayout(new MigLayout("insets 0, gap 10" ));
            Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            int locationX = (screenSize.width-240) / 2;
            int locationY = (screenSize.height -550) / 2;
            canvas.setBounds(locationX, locationY,840, 550);
            panel.add(captureBtn = new JButton("Capture"), " w 100:100:100, h 40:40:40");
            controlPanel.add(acceptBtn =new JButton("Accept"), "w 100:100:100, h 40:40:40");
            controlPanel.add(retakeBtn=new JButton("Retake"), "w 100:100:100, h 40:40:40");
            ActionListener RetakeActionListener = new RetakeActionListener();
            retakeBtn.addActionListener(RetakeActionListener);
            ActionListener AcceptActionListener = new AcceptActionListener();
            acceptBtn.addActionListener(AcceptActionListener);
            ActionListener CaptureActionListener = new CaptureActionListener();
            captureBtn.addActionListener(CaptureActionListener);


            canvas.add(panel,"south");
            capturecanvas.setLayout(new MigLayout("wrap 3"));
            capturecanvas.setVisible(false);
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FrameGrabber.Exception 
        {   
            new FaceDetector();
        }
```

When i try to run it like this from my another class `new FaceDetector();` the components are missing

Code after changes:

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
 public void run() {
     try {
         new FaceDetector();
     } catch (IOException | FrameGrabber.Exception ex) {
                  Logger.getLogger(RegisterService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
 }
 });



 thread.start();
   while (thread.isAlive()==false)
   {
       try {
      DatabaseConnectivity            ndbc = new         DatabaseConnectivity("select","");
   ndbc.FrameShow();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RegisterService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,   null, ex);
        }

}


    }
```

Comment: This problem is commonly caused by running long or non-terminating operations on the UI event dispatching thread

Comment: @ControlAltDel so how to fix it?

Comment: Use a different thread. There are lots of ways to implement this.

Comment: How do you call this class from another class. Do you call it inside a loop or something else? Please share that part too.

Comment: @rdonuk i did. just `new FaceDetector();`. if u want a full code :  `  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {
            new FaceDetector();
            // TODO add your handling code here:
        } catch (IOException | FrameGrabber.Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RegisterService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }     `

Comment: I think you should have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for the cause and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for a possible solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run it within a `Runnable`.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
     public void run() {
         new FaceDetector();
     }
});

thread.start();
```

**Edit:**

```
thread.start();
while(thread.isAlive()){};
try {
     DatabaseConnectivity ndbc = new DatabaseConnectivity("select","");
     ndbc.FrameShow();

} catch (SQLException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(RegisterService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,   null, ex);
}
```

Comment: @rhoduk i did like this `private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                new FaceDetector();
            } catch (IOException | FrameGrabber.Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(RegisterService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        });
    }                                        
`

Comment: Sorry that was the wrong code. Please try the updated one.

Comment: @rhoduk it works fine. ty. as i understand that will create a new thread every time when the button pressed. how can i make sure that it will stop previous thread before running new one?

Comment: Thread will be stopped after execution of `run()` is finished. So you don't have to worry about it. http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/java/threads/states.html

Comment: @rhoduk so it will finish thread even after the FaceDetector constructor will be run not after all actions inside this constructor complete?

Comment: After constructor execution is finished, thread will be stopped.

Comment: @ rdonuk so if execution is not finished yet and the user press the button once more? how to stop thread then before starting another?

Comment: May be checking if thread is finished its job in the `jButton1ActionPerformed` like this `while(thread.isAlive()){};` solve your problem. With this, application will not leave actionPerformed while `thread` is running. And user will not allowed to click again.

Comment: I'd be careful with that as the OP is modifying the state of the ui from within that class, this could cause a number of issues

Comment: @ MadProgrammer than what do u advice?

Comment: @rdonuk probably i did something wrong. cant post all code here. too long. how can i write u pm or something like that?

Comment: What is the problem? You can add code to your question.

Comment: @rdonuk added a code. i need to make button disabled while previous thread is not finished yet and to execute   `  try {
      DatabaseConnectivity            ndbc = new         DatabaseConnectivity("select","");
   ndbc.FrameShow();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RegisterService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,   null, ex);
        }`this code only once after thread is finished

Comment: @rdonuk i still can press the button several times and this part of code   DatabaseConnectivity ndbc = new DatabaseConnectivity("select","");
     ndbc.FrameShow();  is not run at all